# Staff name field won't change when I try to change it

Tags: php, jquery

I have a ticketing system. This is my `call_edit.php` file which i admin and staff users can edit and answer the tickets:
[DEMO](https://ideone.com/SLOMoI)

Problem is when someone send us a ticket , the ticket status is on Open (value= 0 ) and I have a script that you can see it in the code. For the first time I change Staff from None ( value=0) to any of my staff names , it changes and its ok. But when I want to change the staff name again ( for example from staff1 to staff2 after I change the staff name for the first time ) it won't change anymore. If the staff1 change the ticket status to Checking ( value = 2) , no one else can change the staff name. NO ONE. I have to open the ticket again and change the staff name again!
this is my staff names:

```
<tr><td>Staff</td><td><select name='call_staff'>
    <option value="0"></option>
    <?php $staff_name = $db->get_results("select user_id,user_name from site_users where user_level<>1 order by user_name;");
    foreach ($staff_name as $staff )
    {?>
    <option value='<?php echo $staff->user_id;?>'<?php if($staff->user_id == $call_staff){echo ' selected';}?>><?php echo $staff->user_name;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select></td></tr>
```

This is my status:

```
<tr><td valign="top" style="width: 150px;">Status</td>
<td><select type="hidden"  name='call_status'>
<option value='0'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 0){echo ' selected';}?>>باز</option>
<option value='2'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 2){echo ' selected';}?>>در حال بررسی</option>
<option value='1'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 1){echo ' selected';}?>>بسته</option>
<option value='3'<?php if($site_calls->call_status == 3){echo ' selected';}?>>حذف شده</option>
</select> &nbsp; <a href="call_edit.php?call_id=<?php echo $call_id;?>&action=delete&nacl=<?php echo $nacl;?>" onclick="return confirm('آیا مطمعن هستید میخواهید حذف کنید؟')"><i class="fa fa-times" title="حذف کردن"></i></a>
</td></tr>
```

and this is my script to automatically change the status from Open ( value = 0 ) to Checking ( value = 2) when staff field value changes from 0 to anything else:

```
<script>
$("[name='call_staff']").change(function(){
if((this.value)!=0)
{
$("[name='call_status']").val(2);
}
else
{
$("[name='call_status']").val(0);
}
}).change();
</script>
```

Comment: OK if u dont know the answer , u dont need to do -rep! if ur noob its not my problem :)

Comment: just keep it in mind that i dont give a /?/? about -rep :)

Comment: Nor about this community, it seems.

Comment: Wasted my dupehammer but literally character-for-character duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31212373/560648. Please somebody with more sense "do the needful" for me...

Comment: Nor about anything :)

Comment: Then this is not going to work. Should be obvious, really. Life lessons first, programming lessons later.

Comment: thats my question TOO , but no one answered. i dont think that i have to answer to u!

Comment: Your the best guy , ur the king ok, now GTFO

Answer (score -1):

Your code is full of errors and will never ever run correctly. You need to do some major syntax solving pretty much line by line, look at your code, check it's correct syntax and fix each line, there's issues.

Also you need to be aware that javascript will not interact with the PHP or the database unless you write some ajax or other server side receiver code for the javascript changes.

But,
In principle to solve your case,
You need to rewrite your code to make `status <> 0` still be loadable and editable, currently you have it that if `status = 0` then you can load and edit the staff row, but you need to widen your code to edit when values are not simply on the zero.

Comment: i just wanted u to see the code, not the full code of my website

Comment: and value <> 0 for staff or status?

Comment: normal user level value is 1. admin is 0 . staff is 2.
and Open status value = 0 , closed is 1, checking is 2 , deleted is 3

Comment: status, and while I have no problem with seeing your code, SO is for question and answers to programming issues, and I've given you an answer that your code has multiple issues, almost every line has a syntax error on it. I will update my answer now to show status :)

Comment: thnx buddy and another question, how to rewrite my code to make status <> 0 and still be loadable and editable ?

Comment: You'd have to add extra routines for each scenario.

Comment: can you tell me what to do exactly  please mate?

Comment: I don't know what to do *exactly*, but I can point you in the right direction. If it was my code I would write it in a completely different way, first off remove the `;` from inside the MySQL query.

Comment: find me on yahoo messenger

Comment: add me on yahoo : aria.darkkkis